# Need help graphing polar equation $r=\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$

Tags: polar-coordinates

I know this is not preferable but since I don't know how to create graphs, I've just uploaded images of my work.

[image]

I first checked for symmetries (that's what the initial table is). Then I graphed the function on the $r\theta-$ plane

Then I graphed it on the $xy-$ plane. This is where I'm running into trouble. [image]

From 0 to $\pi$ the graph goes from radius 0 to 1. I put that on the left side of the $xy$ plane since that is where an angle of $\pi$ radians would be.

Then from $\pi$ to $2\pi$ it goes from radius 1 to radius 0. I think I got this part correct.

Where I'm struggling is from $2\pi$ to $3\pi$ because here the graph goes from radius 0 to radius -1. I marked (in green) everything I graphed from $2\pi$ to $4\pi$ and it should just be a repeat of what is happening from $0$ to $2\pi$.

I marked where $3\pi$ is on the graph, is this correct? Because the solutions show that this is the final image:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $ \ \theta \ = \ 3\pi \ $ is the same as $ \ \theta \ = \ \pi \ \ , $ so $ \ (-1 \ , \ 3 \pi) \ $ is plotted at $ \ (1 , 0 ) \ \ , $ and similarly for the other points in the interval $ \ [2 \pi \ , \  4 \pi] \ \ . $  So you get two "mirror-imaged" cardioids.   The right-hand cardioid get "traced" in the _clockwise_ direction, so the full curve is traced in one continuous loop.

Comment: But if $\theta=3\pi$ is the same as $\theta=\pi$ then wouldn't it be plotted at $(-1,0)$? Why is it on the right side of the graph if $\theta =3\pi$ is on the left side of the graph?

Comment: "Negative radius" is plotted as positive radius from the origin in the opposite direction:  $ \ ( -r \ , \ \theta) \ \rightarrow \ ( |-r| \ , \ -\theta) \ \ . $ This is a convention in plotting polar coordinates.

Comment: I think I understand. So whenever i have a negative radius, I should do this?

Comment: That is how a negative radius from $ \ r \ = \ f(\theta) \ $ is interpreted for a graph in polar coordinates.  (This can lead to "re-tracing" of a curve, as with $ \ r \ = \ \sin \theta \ \ , $ for instance. There, the circle is covered twice in the interval $ \ [0 \ , \ 2\pi] \ \ . $ )